# How to update minor version number in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Currently, I want to update the minor version in a text file using a bash command. This is the format I am dealing with: MAJOR.Minor.BugFix. I am able to increment the BugFix version number but have been unable to increment just the minor version.

I.e

```
01.01.00-> 01.02.00
01.99.00-> 02.00.00
```

This is the code snippet I found online and was trying to tweak to update the minor instead of the bug fix

```
echo 01.00.1 | awk -F. -v OFS=. 'NF==1{print ++$NF}; NF>1{if(length($NF+1)>length($NF))$(NF-1)++; $NF=sprintf("%0*d", length($NF), ($NF+1)%(10^length($NF))); print}'
```

Comment: That `awk` command line would probably be a heck of a lot easier to understand if you were to spread it across multiple lines and indent it a bit to reflect its structure.

Comment: @wcarhart, consider `$(( ))` (POSIX-compliant math syntax, mandated since the 1992 publication of POSIX.2) instead of `expr` (a holdout from the 1970s). See also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: Two digits are mandatory for minor version for less than 10?

Comment: One-liner: `<<<'01.01.00' IFS='.' read -r a b c; printf '%02d.%02d.%02d' $a $((b+1)) $c`

Comment: @LéaGris That will fail on `01.09.00`. You'll need to guard against leading zeroes indicating octal. Use `$((10#$b+1))`.

Answer (score 3):

As `-F` takes a regular expression `-F.` will match any character. Do something like `-F"[.]"` to make it match periods and you can just split fields without any of the *length()* stuff.

[larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks) idea of splitting into multiple lines is a good one:

```
echo $a | awk -F'[.]'  '{
    major=$1;
    minor=$2;
    patch=$3;
    minor += 1;
    major += minor / 100;
    minor = minor % 100;
    printf( "%02d.%02d.%02d\n", major, minor, patch );
    }'
```

Comment: This solution assumes exactly three dot delimited fields on each line.

Comment: Great solution, just curious why the use of `major, minor, patch` instead of just using `$1, $2, $3`? For readability? Either way, still a good solution.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Decades ago I picked up a dislike of obscure variable names. Yeas $1 $2 $3 are common, built-in, popular, and all that. But it longer names are easier to understand, observe typos in, self-documenting, and other nifty things to make future maintenance easier. Designing for maintenance is key to reducing future bugs.

Comment: That's exactly what it looked like -- and it would be more readable for those not familiar with `awk` *field* numbering.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: yes. Of all the code shown here which would you prefer to be asked to change if you never saw it before, or if your own, two years from now? Always take mercy on future maintainers, for they may be you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need AWK for this, just `read` with `IFS=.` will do.

Though in Bash, leading zeroes indicate octal so you'll need to guard against them.

```
IFS=. read -r major minor bugfix <<< "$1"

# Specify base 10 in case of leading zeroes (octal)
((major=10#$major, minor=10#$minor, bugfix=10#$bugfix))

if [[ $minor -eq 99 ]]; then
    ((major++, minor=0))
else
    ((minor++))
fi

printf '%02d.%02d.%02d\n' "$major" "$minor" "$bugfix"
```

Test run:

```
$ ./test.sh 01.01.00
01.02.00
$ ./test.sh 01.99.09
02.00.09
$ ./test.sh 1.1.1
01.02.01
```

Comment: This does not work with the example `01.99.00` given in the question, where the minor value should carry over to the major: `01.99.00 --> 02.00.00`. This solution produces `01.99.00 --> 01.100.00`

Comment: @wcarhart Oh, I hadn't noticed that. Should be easy to adapt though, just a bit of math. I'll add to it later.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer:

```
version=01.02.00
newversion="$(printf "%06d" "$(expr "$(echo $version | sed 's/\.//g')" + 100)")"
echo "${newversion:0:2}.${newversion:2:2}.${newversion:4:2}"
```

Full explanation:

```
version=01.02.00

# get the number without decimals
rawnumber="$(echo $version | sed 's/\.//g')"

# add 100 to number (to increment minor version)
sum="$(expr "$rawnumber" + 100)"

# make number 6 digits
newnumber="$(printf "%06d" "$sum")"

# add decimals back to number
newversion="${newnumber:0:2}.${newnumber:2:2}.${newnumber:4:2}"
echo "$newversion"
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` provides a simple and efficient way to handle updating the minor-version (and increment the major-version if the minor version is `99` and setting the minor-version zero), e.g.

```
awk -F'.' '{
    if ($2 == 99) {
        $1++
        $2=0
    }
    else
        $2++
    printf "%02d.%02d.%02d\n", $1, $2 ,$3
}' minorver
```

Above the leading-zeros are are ignored when considered as a number and then it is just a simple comparison of the *minor-version* to determine whether to increment the *major-version* and zero the *minor-version* or simply increment the *minor-version*. The `printf` is used to provide the formatted output:

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in the file `minorver`, you can do:

```
$ awk -F'.' '{
>     if ($2 == 99) {
>         $1++
>         $2=0
>     }
>     else
>         $2++
>     printf "%02d.%02d.%02d\n", $1, $2 ,$3
> }' minorver
01.02.00
02.00.00
```

Let me know if you have further questions.